# How to start with back yard space exploration?

Tags: telescope

I am completely noob to space science. Recently, I visited to my cousins and found amazing experience of observing Moon with telescope. The one that they uses is "Monocular Outdoor High Definition Terrestrial Astronomical Telescope". I want to know how should I start with space exploration and which type of telescope is suitable for this kind of adventure?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This question is better suited for [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com) as it has nothing to do with space _exploration_. Please ask your question there, but I'm afraid even then it's out of scope for the site as it's too broad and opinion-based. Please [see the tour of Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what kind of questions this site is suitable for (important point: this is not a forum, lengthy discussions are not the goal of StackExchange sites).

Comment: BTW, for armchair space-explorer, I'd recommend [Orbiter](http://orbit.medphys.ucl.ac.uk/) - more realistic but also more limited spacecraft simulator, and [Kerbal Space Program](https://www.kerbalspaceprogram.com/en/) - which replaces some most harsh aspects of spaceflight with more 'friendly' counterparts, but provides much more flexibility, especially in spacecraft design.

Comment: @SF. simulators and games do not explore space. They are video games. Conflagration of *looking at the real universe in the night sky with a telescope* with sitting indoors playing video games is cynical at best.